# Do you know what CDTU means?

Tags: database, heroku, cleardb

I'm new to ClearDB. In the dashboard is one gauge called CDTU. 
What does CDTU mean? I already googled but cant find anything.
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of data does it show?

Comment: Its a basic car like gauge. It can't be CPU because CPU got its own gauge.
I added a pic here: https://imgur.com/a/hWq8g5P

Comment: Does mousing over the gauge show anything?

Comment: No, nothing. Also checked the HTML, also no hints there.